# Rails: callback on another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In an application I have, there are 2 models: `Comment` and `User`

I want for example to be able to call a method in `User` when `Comment` is updated; as an example `send_email`. Why not just write send_email in `Comment`? Because then I'd be contradicting encapsulation.

My question then is, what is the right way to call a callback method on another model. Example:

```
after_update :user.send_email
```

Comment: The `after_update` param can be a method symbol, a callback object, or a inline method/proc. Which makes the most sense depends on context; I'd use a proc here until it gets complex--the drawback being that as soon as you want to log or something from the callback it's probably better expressed as a method or callback object. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right, after_update can be used for the callback.Assuming the comment and user mappings generically

```
#comment.rb
after_update :send_email_to_user
private
def send_email_to_user
  user.send_email
end    

#user.rb
def send_email
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`after_update` takes either the name of a method. In your example `:user.send_email` is not a valid method name. One way is to create a method that calls `send_email` on the user object, and then register this as the callback. See Rails Guides for full documentation on [Active Record Callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html).

```
after_update :send_email

def send_email
  user.send_email
end
```